# I want to compare country list with column data which is dictionary object type in pandas dataframe Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary, compare

```
list = ['Japan', 'France', 'United States']
```

want to compare list with column name **place** key 'country' and value ''
get only those rows which have countries similar to countries in list

the dataframe look like this:

```
Id        Place
767       {'country_code': 'US','country': 'United States'}
645       {'country_code': 'IRL','country': 'Ireland'}
324       {'country_code': 'JAP','country': 'Japan'}
```

i have used this:

```
 for i in range(0,len(df['place'])):
      df['place'][0]["country"].isin(list)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use, [`Series.str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) along with [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to create a *boolean mask* then filter the rows using this mask:

```
m = df['Place'].str.get('country').isin(lst)
df = df[m]
```

---

```
# print(df)
    Id                                              Place
0  767  {'country_code': 'US', 'country': 'United States'}
2  324        {'country_code': 'JAP', 'country': 'Japan'}
```

Comment: thank you shubham sharma it worked correctly as I needed. it was my first question on stackoverflow and answered in just few minutes.